# What noticeable effects do slow ping times have?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping, speed, 802.11n

On a network that I volunteer to help maintain, I installed a router that (unfortunately) increases average ping times by almost double - from 17ms (average) to 30ms (average) - for 802.11n 2.4GHz WiFi users.

Throughput speed is significantly (20%) faster with the new router, however.

These figures were generated solely using [speedtest.net](http://beta.speedtest.net) and [speedsmart.net](http://speedsmart.net/) using consistent servers within each site.

***What noticeable effects will these slower ping times have for users of that network?  Will the increase in throughput speed negate these effects?***

According to the logs, the network is used for the following purposes (in order of usage):

1. extensive web browsing
2. substantial webmail use
3. web applications
4. game playing
5. video watching
6. VoIP
7. chat
8. audio listening
9. misc

Comment: Considering that 16ms is the per-frame refresh time of a 60hz display you are talking about very small differences in latency.  Compared to the round trip time for packet go in to the other side of the world this is negligible and chances are most people will find it irrelevant unless they are playing twitch shooting games on high refresh rate monitors. We used to play on connections with much higher latencies, that ping isn't "slow" by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Are you saying you're testing your ping times with servers *outside* your LAN? That's a rather unreliable way to confirm the performance of a piece of gear, even if you do use the same target servers. It would be preferable to test against an internal device, or at minimum, the next-hop upstream router in your ISP's network.

Comment: Unless the network is used for heavy professional gaming a little extra lag should not be an issue. However the increase in lag can indicate that it will increase further during congestion, keep that in mind.

Comment: @Barfieldmv - I don't believe there is correlation between lag and congestion.   Lag is a result of distance and time to process packets. (an increase in jitter would indicate congestion - but lag != jitter).  Indeed, the more bandwidth the LESS increase in lag caused by congestion (because more packets can be scheduled in the same amount of time then a lower bandwidth connection).   I am in New Zealand, and have a connection with 80ms lag in Singapore.   I get better throughput then people with a 50ms connection to it in Australia - because I have a faster home connection.

Answer (score 2):

The major problem is not the fact that the `ping` response time has increased, `ping` is just a command that uses the `ICMP` protocol which is rarely used more than to measure response times between sending/receiving packets. This is a command that is mostly used on demand (there are some commands/protocols based on it, though).

The real problem is what a major response time implies. The fact that the `ping` response time has increased, in practice means that probably other packets will also take longer to be delivered (assuming the response time increase is not happening because you have some issues with your `ICMP` protocol configuration).

However, I wouldn't worry too much about the ping response time if you really see the global speed has increased, but would test it conscientiously to actually confirm that this is just a `ICMP` issue and is not affecting the global speed of your users.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer.  I have updated my question to provide more details.  I did not directly use the `ping` command (well, I tried, but it was blocked by the firewall, and I didn't have time to mess with it); instead I used two sites that provide ping estimates.

Comment: I would not rely too much on external websites for `ping` measurements. Keep in mind that when you're measuring response times, from point `A` (the website you're using) to point `B` there are a number of hops in the middle, which can increase the delay of the measurement, and as you can't know how they're configured nor if they're experiencing some kind of network difficulties, I wouldn't consider these measurements reliable. Instead use your LAN to do so.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, an extra 15ms or so is inconsequential.

It would only be consequence if playing an online game where reflexes are vital - and only then at a professional level to servers located close to you.

It could be discernable but not annoying for browsing/applications/VOIP/webmail/remote server admin.

It would have no  real impact on video / audio watching or text chatting.

A few things to bear in mind - Many locations you interact with will not be in your state. 15ms represents - very roughly - 2000 miles distance. Sites halfway arround the world will have pings over 300ms, so 15ms is not important.  It is not unreasonable, although wifi need not add more the 5ms in typical networks.

What might be more relevant is throughput, packet loss and jitter (ie the difference between fast and slow pings). If you have close to no packet loss, and low jitter, a slightly higher latency is probably preferable to a lower latency, lower throughput connection - especially as latency will increase more when a slower connection is in use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compensate response time with throughput.

Any application where response time is critical might see issues. What those might be depends on the application. A usual example would be VOIP where noticeable delays can annoy users or make VOIP unusable as you won't be able to talk in a sensible way.

In most cases the increase in delay (in this case) probably won't be much of an issue.

Comment: You an sometimes compensate for response time with thoughput - For example - with VOIP applications you can do tighter compression and reduce the packet size to somewhat compensate.  A higher MOS can also help.  In a pure VOIP connection, VOIP works fine with < 30ms latency, and in reality it works acceptably with > 200ms latency [ see Cellphones, long distance calls ].  The only gotcha is echo, which might require tuning with an echo canceler.